# Set php array values also as key

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

What is the easiest way to convert an array like that:

```
array('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3');
```

into this:

```
array(
'Item 1' => 'Item 1',
'Item 2' => 'Item 2',
'Item 3' => 'Item 3',
);
```

Note: Maybe its relevant. I got that first array by php explode();

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: http://php.net/array_combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_combine(array('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'), array('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way is to use [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.

Example:

```
$data = array('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3');
$result = array_combine($data, $data);
```